# How to change parameter in a child class method?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Let's say I have a following class:

```
class LearningMethod {
public:
    virtual void optimize( lib4neuro::ErrorFunction &ef, std::ofstream* ofs = nullptr ) = 0;

    virtual std::vector<double>* get_parameters( ) = 0;
};
```

And now I'll inherit from it and create a new class, where `optimize()` method will accept `ErrorFunctionDifferentiable` type, which inherits from `ErrorFunction` itself.

```
class GradientLearningMethod : public LearningMethod {
    virtual void optimize( lib4neuro::ErrorFunctionDifferentiable &ef, std::ofstream* ofs = nullptr ) = 0;
};
```

Is there any correct way how to implement this? Compiler thinks, that I'm creating a new method and not overwriting an old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any correct way how to implement this? Compiler thinks, that I'm creating a new method and not overwriting an old one.

1. Change the `virtual` member function in the derived class to use same argument type, i.e. `lib4neuro::ErrorFunction &`.
2. Add a member function in the derived class that accepts an argument of type `lib4neuro::ErrorFunctionDifferentiable &`. This function can use the same name or a different name – it's immaterial.
3. Perform `dynamic_cast` on the argument passed to the first function to `lib4neuro::ErrorFunctionDifferentiable &` in the overridden `virtual` member function. If the `dynamic_cast` succeeds, call the second function with the successfuly cast object. If not, you will have to figure out how to deal with it.